# Getting the file path of iOS image for use in Unity

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, uiimagepickercontroller

I need to get a file path for an iOS image to use it for a project I'm working on in Unity.
So far I have this code:

```
#pragma mark - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
// This method is called when an image has been chosen from the library or taken from the camera.
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)info
{
    NSString *type = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    NSLog(@"type=%@",type);
    if ([type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
    {
        NSURL* imageURL = (NSURL *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
        NSString *urlString = [imageURL absoluteString];

        const char* cp = [urlString UTF8String];
        if(cp)
            strcpy(image_path, cp);
        else
        {//If the image path is unasigned give ERROR instead
            char* error = "ERROR";
            strcpy(image_path, error);
        }
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    // UnitySendMessage("GameObject", "VideoPicked", video_url_path);
    UnitySendMessage(callback_game_object_name, callback_function_name, image_path);
}
```

This however returns the image address in a format similar to the following:

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=92C96E1D-F714-49E6-8074-5B5980FF944F&ext=JPG
```

Which as far as I can tell is only useful for iPhone libraries,
is there a way to get its actual path, or am completely going down the wrong route?

As a side note the Unity code is completely fine, can get unity to receive the string etc. but it doesn't know what to do with it.

EDIT: This function got it to work for me thanks to Pankaj for his response

```
// This method is called when an image has been chosen from the library or taken from the camera.
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)info
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"setName.png"];

    //save image here and then use that imagePath
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){
        UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage);
        [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
    }
    NSLog(@"imagePath=%@",imagePath);
    const char* cp = [imagePath UTF8String];
    strcpy(image_path, cp);

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    UnitySendMessage(callback_game_object_name, callback_function_name, image_path);
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not an expert but I do not see any C# code in here.

Comment: if you are getting image from pickerView then you can store that image in that directory and then you can use that directory path for your Unity work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get image from PickerView and then store it in document directory then use that path for Unity.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"setName.png"];

//save image here and then use that imagePath
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){
    UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage);
    [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
}

UnitySendMessage(callback_game_object_name, callback_function_name, imagePath);
```